# How could i find out the day of the week that has the lowest number of single rider trips on average?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Below is my code but only returns the total amount of ride that is a single ride. I tried to apply two aggregate functions together (min and count) but didn't work

```
select count(VendorID) as num_1
from Yellow_trip_data
where passenger_count=1 and RatecodeID = 1
GROUP BY dayofweek(tpep_pickup_datetime);

8569039
10840901
10470560
10965369
10697947
9850593
9591603
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve].)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: spark sql and google cloud

Comment: you can find the data link here https://www1.nyc.gov/site/tlc/about/tlc-trip-record-data.page. It's the Yellow Taxi data file.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH YourQuery as (
    select dayofweek(tpep_pickup_datetime as day_of_week, count(VendorID) as num_1
    from Yellow_trip_data
    where passenger_count=1 and RatecodeID = 1
    GROUP BY dayofweek(tpep_pickup_datetime))
SELECT day_of_week from YourQuery ORDER BY num_1 ASC LIMIT 1
```

I just used your query and selected the minimum number.

If you want to show the average:

```
WITH SingleRiderCountsPerDay AS (  
        select date_trunc(tpep_pickup_datetime,'DD') as pickup_date, count(VendorID) as number_of_rides
        from Yellow_trip_data
        where passenger_count=1 and RatecodeID = 1
        GROUP BY date_trunc(tpep_pickup_datetime,'DD')
), AverageSingleRidesPerWeekday AS (
        select dayofweek(pickup_date) as day_of_week, AVG(number_of_rides) as average_number_of_rides
        from SingleRiderCountsPerDay
        GROUP BY dayofweek(pickup_date)
) SELECT day_of_week, average_number_of_rides from AverageSingleRidesPerWeekday ORDER BY num_1 ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: the question was asking 'on average', that's the part I am struggling with.